# Add more text to textView android

Tags: android, textview

I have a really simple question but i can't seem to figure it out. So i have this fairly large textview and i want to have twelve rows of text that each have a word. But when i edit in the xml it only lets me have one android:text attribute. How could i do this?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="speed"
        android:text="air speed"
         />
```

So i want to have more text attributes like shown in the code.

Comment: You can add text to a textview programmatically using `textview.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the newline character `\n`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="speed\nair speed" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set texxt in your textview with java code using **HTml.from html** tag like:

```
TextView tvInformation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_information);
tvInformation.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br>"+"</br>" + "row1 text" + "<br>"+"</br>" + "row2 text");
```

similarly  you can add 12 or more rows as per your requirement.  this 
 tag is used for next line as  we use \n in string.